# Not able to find the element to click | Selenium Webdriver | Add New User Issue | Getting java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium2

```
package com.MainExecutionforWordpress;
```

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.AD.Wordpress.Login.CallLoginPageElementsHere;
import com.AddNewUser.AddNewUserLogic;
import com.AddNewUser.RetrieveNewUserData;

public class TestWordpressHere
{

```
 CallLoginPageElementsHere login = new CallLoginPageElementsHere();
 AddNewUserLogic addnew = new AddNewUserLogic();
```

@Test(dataProvider = "dprovider")
  public void Wordpress_Execution_starts_here(String username, String password )
  {
    // try below approach also to open the browser
      login.callinsetupmethod();
      login.Login(username,password);
      Assert.assertEquals(true, login.IsatHomepage());

}

@DataProvider
  public String[][] dprovider()
  {
      String [][] user = new String[1][2];

```
// i stands for number of times test case should run
// j stands for number of parameters it should send at one go
  user[0][0] = "admin";
  user[0][1] = "tarunkamina";

return user;
```

}

@Test(dataProvider = "userdataprovider")
  public void NewUserWillBeAddedFromHere(String newuser, String EmailId, String fname, String lname, String websitename)
  {
      AddNewUserLogic.AddNewUserHere(newuser, EmailId, fname, lname, websitename);

```
// Add New User Repository
package com.AddNewUser;
```

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import com.SetUpMethodRepo.DriverMethod;

public class AddNewUserRepo
{
    public static WebElement UsersObjXpath()
    {
        return DriverMethod.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu-users']/a/div[3]"));
    }

```
public static WebElement AddNewObjXpath()
{
    return DriverMethod.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menu-users']/ul/li[3]/a"));
}

public static WebElement UsernameFieldObjXpath()
{
    return DriverMethod.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='user_login']"));
}

public static WebElement EmailFieldObjXpath()
{
    return DriverMethod.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']"));
}

public static WebElement FirstNameObjXpath()
{
    return DriverMethod.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='first_name']"));
}


public static WebElement LastNameObjXpath()
{
    return DriverMethod.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='last_name']"));
}

public static WebElement WebSiteObjXpath()
{
    return DriverMethod.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='url']"));
}

public static WebElement UncheckTheCheckBox()
{
    return DriverMethod.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='send_user_notification']"));
}

public static WebElement AddNewUserObjXpath()
{
    return DriverMethod.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='createusersub']"));
}

public static WebElement NewUserCreated()
{
    return DriverMethod.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='message']/p"));

}
```

}

```
// // Add New User Logic
package com.AddNewUser;
```

public class AddNewUserLogic
{
  public static  void AddNewUserHere(String newuser, String EmailId, String fname, String lname, String websitename)
  {
      AddNewUserRepo.UsersObjXpath().click();
      AddNewUserRepo.AddNewObjXpath().click();
      AddNewUserRepo.UsernameFieldObjXpath().sendKeys(newuser);
      AddNewUserRepo.EmailFieldObjXpath().sendKeys(EmailId);
      AddNewUserRepo.FirstNameObjXpath().sendKeys(fname);
      AddNewUserRepo.LastNameObjXpath().sendKeys(lname);
      AddNewUserRepo.WebSiteObjXpath().sendKeys(websitename);
      AddNewUserRepo.UncheckTheCheckBox().click();
      AddNewUserRepo.AddNewUserObjXpath().click();

}

public static  boolean Check_If_NewUser_Is_Created() // Validating new user
  {
      if(AddNewUserRepo.NewUserCreated().getText().contains("New user created"))
      {
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
          return false;
      }
  }

}

```
package com.AddNewUser;
```

import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;
import org.openqa.jetty.start.Main;

public class RetrieveNewUserData
{
  public static String [][] FetchUserDataFromHere()
  {
      String filepath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "\src\test\resources\NewUserData.properties";
      System.out.println(filepath);

```
  try {
    PropertiesConfiguration conf = new PropertiesConfiguration(filepath);
    Iterator<String> itr = conf.getKeys();

      String [][] user = new String[1][5];
      while(itr.hasNext())
      {
          for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
          {
              for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
              {
                 user[i][j]= conf.getString(itr.next()) ;
              }
          }
          System.out.println("Inside While loop....");
      }
      return user;


} catch (ConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}


 return null;
```

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FetchUserDataFromHere();
    System.out.println("user data");
}
}

```
// Setup method
package com.SetUpMethodRepo;
```

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class DriverMethod
{
  public static WebDriver driver = null;

public static void SetUp()
  {
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.get("http://abhidwi.byethost17.com/wp/wp-admin/");

```
 // driver.get("http://abhidwi.byethost17.com/wp/wp-admin/");
```

}
}

Comment: I tell you what I am trying to do. I have created a class for setup() method in a package. Then I created a different package and created two classes, 1 for objectrepo and 2. to call those objectrepo methods. I kept the logic for login() in a different package so there are three packages. 1-> for setup() 2-> for login() and 3-> to add new user. Now I am trying to use @Test annotation for login() and addnewuser(). When I run the script, I am able to login but then script stops and gives an error message java.lang.nullpointer exception.

Comment: @dzieciou  I am sure that there is a problem with driver, perhaps it find it null. Could you please help me out figuring out the solution. I am new to programming and hence finding it difficult.

Comment: Is there any question? Did you provide the exception? I see only some code

Comment: of course I have a question. I am not able to add new user using below approach

Comment: @Test(dataProvider = "userdataprovider")
  public void NewUserWillBeAddedFromHere(String newuser, String EmailId, String fname, String lname, String websitename)
  {
      AddNewUserLogic.AddNewUserHere(newuser, EmailId, fname, lname, websitename);
      Assert.assertEquals(true, AddNewUserLogic.Check_If_NewUser_Is_Created());
  }

Comment: your comments are unreadable. Please use code formatting. Please edit your question: provide exception you got. "I am not able to add new user" is not question

Comment: And also write what you've already done (something like in you first comment)

Comment: @kotoj is it helpful now?

Comment: No. There are still no question / exception / code formatting. There are more code with any explanation.

Comment: can I have your email id please. I find formatting in here- challenging. I am not used to this site. I will send you the project.

Comment: No. What about if you have another problem? Will you send me a question again? Learn this site and how to ask questions. When you edit question you have preview, please try to format and see how it looks. When you ask question you have tips on the right side. I've asked you about the exception you got 3 times and you have not provided it so I cannot to help you.

Comment: @kotoj can you please check now. I have put all the related codes. and the error is java.lang.nullpointerexception at line 14 which is at AddNewUserRepo.UsersObjXpath().click();

Comment: Why didnt you put your exception to question? Formatting still is not so good, but ok... Does at least firefox open using this code?

Comment: yep, Firefox gets opened but it doesn't click on the link i.e. AddNewUserRepo.UsersObjXpath().click(); => doesn't work

Comment: Please edit  question with exception message. and please remove unnecessary code as it makes very difficult and annoying at the same time.  btw, I don't see Setup method is called up anywhere, unless I am missing out something here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to SQA.

Instead of me investigating what happens in this particular case, I think it will be more helpful for this and similar questions to understand how to

- [read stacktrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)
- [see an actual value of your variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239150/looking-for-an-easier-way-to-write-debugging-print-statements-in-java) (i.e., debug with `System.out.println()`).
- read from JavaDoc for Java API, what each exception means, e.g., [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

That will be useful to you not only in this particular case but also in your further adventure with test automation and generally programming.

Another option is to pair with a programmer in your company or your city and learn from him or her. My experience is that watching how someone else  investigating a problem is much better way to learn things than explaining that here. This is a classical example of tacit knowledge.

Comment: If it's more helpful, but not an answer to the question, then this should be a comment. Stack Exchange avoids boilerplate answers. Boilerplate comments, those are a little more okay. (I see the irony here. I do.)

Comment: @corsiKa I agree it does not answer the question directly. But decision whether something is an answer is subjective here, and up to the OP. And in this question s/he accepted it as an answer. If I had answered directly what the OP had asked for that would have been boilerplate answer: repeating what NullPointerException is. Every week I see an instance of the same problem on this forum: why do I have NullPointerException here. Marking them as off-topic (they are about programming) or duplicate (same class of NPE problems) does not seem to prevent those questions from coming.

Comment: Keep voting to close as off-topic or duplicate. That's the model.